# Don't return row when all values are NULL - SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift, but I suspect this will be valuable to many other forms of SQL.  I am also new to SQL and would appreciate any advice on my query, other than advice which pertains specifically to my question; just please keep it constructive.

QUESTION: How do I avoid returning rows where all rows of my result are NULL?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN events.event_id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT event_id FROM strings_ref WHERE string_id = 123)
        THEN event_id END AS 123, 
    CASE WHEN events.event_id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT event_id FROM strings_ref WHERE string_id = 456)
        THEN event_id END AS 456
    FROM events
```

There are many many other `string_id`s, and this query just returned 1000 consecutive NULLS.  EDIT: I have verified that there are results.

NOTE: I have accepted the answer that most pertains to my question, but @gordon-linoff 's answer is more general.

Comment: I think this would be much clearer if you shared some sample data and your desired results. Your query is very strange and could be solved simply by aggregating and using a CASE statement instead of subquerying to return the same thing you are returning anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT E.*, SR1.EVENT_ID, SR2.EVENT_ID
FROM Events E
    LEFT OUTER JOIN strings_ref sr1 on E.EVENT_ID=SR1.EVENT_ID AND sr1.string_id = 123
    LEFT OUTER JOIN strings_ref sr2 on E.EVENT_ID=SR2.EVENT_ID AND sr2.string_id = 456
WHERE SR1.EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL OR SR2.EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Join on strings_ref multiple times

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN e.event_id IN (SELECT sr.event_id FROM strings_ref sr WHERE sr.string_id = 123)
                   THEN e.event_id
              END) AS e_123, 
             (CASE WHEN e.event_id IN (SELECT sr.event_id FROM strings_ref sr WHERE sr.string_id = 456)
                  THEN e.event_id
              END) AS e_456
      FROM events e
     ) e
WHERE e_123 IS NOT NULL or e_456 IS NOT NULL;
```

Some advice:

- Qualify *all* column names in the query.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table name.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed with `IN`.
- Give your columns names that don't look like numbers.

Comment: Thanks,My theory with the DISTINCT clause was to speed up processing the IN condition.  Is the DISTINCT likely to take more time than it saves?

Comment: @ChootsMagoots . . . It is immaterial.  Let the compiler decide the best approach for handling the `IN`.